# R impute data using horizontal mean/mode/etc

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I would like to impute missing values based on row mean instead of column mean.

```
id       Price1         Price2           Price3        Price4    HorizontalMean
004        NA             101              103           114            106
005       100             108               78            99             96.25
006        34              33               NA            78             48.333
...
```

I've looked at a few packages and can't seem to find any that explicitly mention it.  Any recommendations or do I need to do a transpose first (this could be a problem as the data is >100k lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice little one-liner:

```
> df <- data.frame(Price1 = c(NA, 100, 34),
+                  Price2 = c(101, 108, 33),
+                  Price3 = c(103, 78, NA),
+                  Price4 = c(114, 99, 78))
> df
  Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4
1     NA    101    103    114
2    100    108     78     99
3     34     33     NA     78

> df <- ifelse(is.na(df), rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE), unlist(df))
> df
     Price1 Price2    Price3 Price4
[1,]    106    101 103.00000    114
[2,]    100    108  78.00000     99
[3,]     34     33  48.33333     78
```

EDIT: for @Charlie who asked how would you do to replace NAs with column means, you could    use the same thing but replace rowMeans(...) with a vector repeating the column means:

```
df <- ifelse(is.na(df), rep(colMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE), rep(nrow(df), ncol(df))),
             unlist(df))
```

or apply ifelse to each column of the list:

```
df <- sapply(df, function(x)ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x))
```

Comment: +1 Neat. How would you replace NAs with column-wise means without transposing df twice?

Comment: Thank you @flodel, I was just curious to learn a way of replacing NAs without using *apply. I usually rely on the which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE) solution for this kind of issues.

Comment: Using this, I lose the row.names in my data.frame object. is there a way to keep them?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually, with `apply` and `ifelse`.

```
# Sample data
d <- matrix(rnorm(20), nc=2)
d[ sample(1:20,3) ] <- NA
d <- as.data.frame(d)
d$mean <- apply(d, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

# Replace missing values, only in the first two columns
d[,1:2] <- apply( 
  d[,1:2], 
  2, 
  function(u) ifelse(is.na(u), d$mean, u) 
)
```